# Nilpotent matrices proof of A^n=0

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I’ve got a question that goes like this;

Let A ∈ R^(n×n) be a square matrix satisfying that A^(N) = 0 for sufficiently large N > 0, i.e. a matrix power of A becomes the zero matrix. Show that     A^(n) = 0

This question has to be answered without eigenvalues.

This is what I’ve accomplished so far:
We maybe need to show that n=>N.

Determinant of A is zero since det(A^(N))=0

Then A is not invertable and pivot postions is lesser than n.

I’ve got a hint from out assistant that told us to prove that kern(A) ⊂ kern(A^N)

I was told that You can show that the kernel of A^(k+1) is strictly bigger than the kernel of A^k until you get the whole space. So in particular A^n =0 since you can't get ker A, ker A^2,...,ker A^n, R^n all different dimensions.

But I dont really understand what to make of this.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Care to explain in which way this question is a [tag:calculus] question or a [tag:reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces] question?

Comment: Sorry, I must have accidentally tagged that.

Comment: Try to show that if $Ker(A^k)=Ker(A^{k+1})$ for some $k$ then $Ker(A^N)=Ker(A^k)$ for all $N\geq k$ by induction for example. It is true for $N=k$ and $N=k+1$ by assumption. So start from $N>k+1$ assuming $Ker(A^{N-1})=Ker(A^k)$. Pick $x\in Ker(A^N)$ and argue that it is in $Ker(A^k)$. Hope this makes some sense=)